# separate arrays in to single array

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

i have the following separate arrays

```
Array
(
    [option] => nos
    [optioncost] => 10
)
Array
(
    [option] => opts
    [optioncost] => 20
)
Array
(
    [option] => opts
    [optioncost] => 30
)
```

how to convert this to single array

Comment: Use array array_merge but due to duplication key, it will keep the last array, if you want all the arrays you have to change the different keys of each array.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out. You may help.

For your reference, [Check this link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

```
$abc = array('abc');     // Your first array
$abc1 = array('abc1');   // Your second array
$abc2 = array('abc1');   // Your third array

$abc3 = array();
array_push($abc3 ,$abc,$abc1,$abc2);
print_r($abc3);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$array_1 = array('option'=>'nos','optioncost'=>'10');
$array_2 = array('option'=>'nos','optioncost'=>'10');
$array_3 = array('option'=>'nos','optioncost'=>'10');

$array_sum = $array_1+$array_2+$array_3;
```

Actaully PHP could handle array addition in early version.